# can't install mean-cli, node, bower, gulp has already been installed

Tags: node.js, npm

shaunstanislaus@Master ~ (master) $ sudo npm install -g mean-cli
Password:
\

> mean-cli@0.10.12 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli
>   node ./scripts/preinstall

sh: node: command not found
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mean-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.0
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! mean-cli@0.10.12 preinstall: `node ./scripts/preinstall`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mean-cli@0.10.12 preinstall script 'node ./scripts/preinstall'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mean-cli package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./scripts/preinstall
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mean-cli
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/shaunstanislaus/npm-debug.log
shaunstanislaus@Master ~ (master) $